# Ideals have the same height

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals

When I solved an exercise, I had got the following situation: I had to show that $I=J$, where $I,J$ are prime ideals of a noetherian ring. I also proved that $I \subset J$ and they have the same height. Then my argument is that: 
Let $f \in J$ be such that not belong to $I$. Let $p_0 \subset  ... \subset p_n$ be a maximal chain of prime ideals of $I$. Let $m$ be the maximal ideal containing $p_n+\left ( f \right )$. This implies that $$\text{height } J > \text{height } I,$$ which is a contradiction. Therefore $I$ and $J$ must be equal. 
Is my argument correct? If yes, whether it is still correct when $I$ and $J$ are not prime ideals? 
Thank you very much for helps.

Comment: If we only know that $I,J$ are prime ideals, then they do not have to be equal. Do you mean, instead of "I also proved that" to write "It is also assumed that"?

Comment: @Arthur I proved $I \subset J$ and I have noway to show the inverse. However, by using height formula, I computed that they have the same height. But I am not sure that they are equal.

Comment: I mean $p$ is $p_n$. Sorry for that, I will edit. Why we get such chain then it shows height $J$ $>$ height $I$. I took the maximal $m$ in order to make sure that there is a longer chain in $J$.

Comment: Hmm well how do you guarantee that $J$ is contained in the maximal ideal containing $\mathfrak{p}_n$ and $f$? As I said earlier, I think $\mathfrak{p}_0 \subset ... \subset \mathfrak{p}_n = I \subset J$ already gives you a longer chain.